# javascript value getting

Tags: javascript

I want to create a stock calculation system with javacript now i have create it there is some problem the problem is that i have created 3 rows 1.Purchase,2.Sold,3.Stock.Now i have set that when i give purchase value and sold quantity it will subtract and print value in stock text box and then is next column the stock value also prints in purcahse text box the problem is when the purchase item become nill means 0 so what can i do to add some quantity and start again this process.
the coding is.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Stock Information</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //------------------------------------Date---------------------------------------------
    var today = new Date();                                                               //
    var dd = today.getDate();                                                             //
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!                                          //
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();                                                       //
    today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;                                                           //   
    document.write(today);                                                                //
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------  
function program(a,b,c,d,e,f)
{
    var total1=a-b;
    document.stock.t3.value=total1;

    var jump1=document.stock.t3.value;
    document.stock.t4.value=jump1;
    var total2= c-d;
    document.stock.t6.value=total2;

    var jump2=document.stock.t6.value;
    document.stock.t7.value=jump2;
    var total3= e-f;
    document.stock.t9.value=total3;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1 class="table">Stock Information</h1>
</center>
<table width="800" align="center" class="table1">
  <tr>
    <th width="260"class="table">Purchase</th>
    <th width="260"class="table">Sold</th>
    <th width="428"class="table">Stock</th>
  </tr>
  <form name="stock">
  <tr align="center">
    <td><input id="t1" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1"/></td>
    <td><input id="t2" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1"/></td>
    <td><input id="t3" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" onClick="program(t1.value,t2.value)" readonly/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td><input id="t4" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" onClick="program(t1.value,t2.value,t4.value,t5.value)"/></td>
    <td><input id="t5" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1"/></td>
    <td><input id="t6" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" onClick="program(t1.value,t2.value,t4.value,t5.value)" readonly/></td>
  </tr>
    <tr align="center">
    <td><input id="t7" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" onClick="program(value1.value,value2.value,t4.value,t5.value)"/></td>
    <td><input id="t8" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1"/></td>
    <td><input id="t9" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" onClick="program(value1.value,value2.value,t4.value,t5.value,t7.value,t8.value)"readonly/></td>
  </tr>
 </form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain more precaisely!

Comment: Sir in this coding there is three rows and three column i have name three columns with 1.Purchase,2.Sold,3.Stock. then i have applied javascript on these text box now i want that when i give the value in purchase text box and sold text box will subtact and gives result in next text box that is stock. then then again on next column whatever the value is in the uper stock text box will print in purchase text box. now the main problem is when tha purchase value become zero 0 so how can i give more value in purchase text box to start this process again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to keep the logic in JavaScript and keep the HTML clean! :)

Instead of `onClic` you could use `onChange`

```
<input onChange="program(this)" />
```

Next, we will calculate everything in JavaScript...

```
function program(el) {
  var fields = document.stock;

  // Do nothing, if the required fields are empty
  if (fields.t1.value == '' || fields.t2.value == '') return;

  // Calculate result
  fields.t3.value = fields.t1.value - fields.t2.value;

  // Do nothing, if the required fields are empty
  if (fields.t4.value == '' || fields.t5.value == '') return;

  // Calculate result
  fields.t6.value = fields.t4.value - fields.t5.value;

  // Do nothing, if the required fields are empty
  if (fields.t7.value == '' || fields.t8.value == '') return;

  // Calculate result
  fields.t9.value = fields.t7.value - fields.t8.value;
}
```

I don't understand exactly how it suppose to work, , but I will try to repeat the same logic, what you did.

I changed the HTML structure a little:

```
<form name="stock">
  <table width="800" align="center" class="table1">
    <tr>
      <th width="260"class="table">Purchase</th>
      <th width="260"class="table">Sold</th>
      <th width="428"class="table">Stock</th>
    </tr>

    <tr align="center">
      <td><input id="t1" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" onChange="program(this)" /></td>
      <td><input id="t2" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" onChange="program(this)" /></td>
      <td><input id="t3" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" readonly /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td><input id="t4" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" readonly /></td>
      <td><input id="t5" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" onChange="program(this)" /></td>
      <td><input id="t6" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" readonly /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td><input id="t7" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" readonly /></td>
      <td><input id="t8" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" onChange="program(this)" /></td>
      <td><input id="t9" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" readonly /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Notice that I did set `t4` and `t7` fields as `readonly`.

And the JavaScript:

```
function program(el) {
  var fields = document.stock;

  // Clear the calculation fields
  fields.t3.value = '';
  fields.t6.value = '';
  fields.t9.value = '';
  fields.t4.value = '';
  fields.t7.value = '';

  // Do nothing, if any of the required fields are empty
  if (fields.t1.value === '' || fields.t2.value === '') return;

  // Calculate result
  fields.t3.value = fields.t1.value - fields.t2.value;

  // Copy the result
  fields.t4.value = fields.t3.value;

  // Do nothing, if the required fields are empty
  if (fields.t5.value === '') return;

  // Calculate result
  fields.t6.value = fields.t4.value - fields.t5.value;

  // Copy the result
  fields.t7.value = fields.t6.value;

  // Do nothing, if the required fields are empty
  if (fields.t8.value === '') return;

  // Calculate result
  fields.t9.value = fields.t7.value - fields.t8.value;
}
```

You can also look at this demo in JSBin: http://jsbin.com/welcome/39835/edit

I hope I got it right.

**UPDATE**
OK, I did some improvements. But instead of checking if the result is `0`, I just allow to write in first place. That function when the result gets copied to the next row's first field, now is just a helper and will not overwrite the value, if the field is not empty. I think that's how it should be.

Slightly changed HTML:

```
<form name="stock">
  <table width="800" align="center" class="table1">
    <tr>
      <th width="260"class="table">Purchase</th>
      <th width="260"class="table">Sold</th>
      <th width="428"class="table">Stock</th>
    </tr>

    <tr align="center">
      <td><input id="t1" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" onChange="program(this)" /></td>
      <td><input id="t2" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" onChange="program(this)" /></td>
      <td><input id="t3" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td><input id="t4" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" onChange="program(this)" /></td>
      <td><input id="t5" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" onChange="program(this)" /></td>
      <td><input id="t6" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td><input id="t7" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" onChange="program(this)" /></td>
      <td><input id="t8" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" onChange="program(this)" /></td>
      <td><input id="t9" type="text" style="width:260px;" class="input1" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

And, most importantly, JavaScript! There is a DOM traversing involved, so you don't need depend on the `id=""` anymore **AND** you can create as many rows you need without changing the JavaScript code.

```
function program(el) {
  // Get the row (the <tr> element)
  var row = el.parentNode.parentNode;

  // Get all the <input> elements in row
  var inputs = row.getElementsByTagName('input');

  // Return, if required fields are empty
  if (inputs[0].value === '' || inputs[1].value === '') {
    inputs[2].value = '';
    return;
  }

  // Calculate the result
  inputs[2].value = inputs[0].value - inputs[1].value;

  // Find the next row (<tr> element)
  var nextRow = row.nextSibling.nextSibling;
  while (nextRow !== null && nextRow.tagName !== 'TR') {
    nextRow = nextRow.nextSibling;
  }

  // Return, if the next row doesn't exist
  if (nextRow === null || nextRow.tagName !== 'TR') return;

  // Get all <input> fields in row
  var nextRowInputs = nextRow.getElementsByTagName('input');

  if (nextRowInputs[0].value === '') {
    // Copy the previous row result into next rows first input,
    // only if it's not filled already
    nextRowInputs[0].value = inputs[2].value;
  }
}
```

And this demo can be tested here: http://jsbin.com/welcome/39893/edit

**Vote this answer up** and give me some points, please! :)

Comment: Sir you are saying right but i want that if my purchase valur become zero. then there is an right to enter value of purchase and then start the previous process.

Comment: @Mufasil.Muhammad.Iqbal I still don't get the idea about what you want to make. So, the `t4` and `t7` are `readonly`, but when they become `0`, they are not `readonly` anymore?

Comment: Sir yes when t4 value become zero t7 autometically remove readyonly and act like t1

Comment: @Mufasil.Muhammad.Iqbal I did update the answer. :)

Comment: Dear Taai:
can you please tell me that what is mean by program(this) in input and waht is means by  el.parentNode.parentNode.

Comment: @Mufasil.Muhammad.Iqbal The `onChange="program(this)"` says that when the value in the field will get changed, the function `program()` will be executed and the `this` is a reference to that element and it's being given as an argument to the function `program`. About that `el.parentNode.parentNode`... I already wrote in the comments - it gets the field element's parent's parent element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.parentNode This is JavaScript. You have to learn it yourself.